# Test suite problems in rails 3.1rc5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I recently upgraded an app i was working on to rails 3.1rc5..

For the most part it's been great but a few of my tests are having really weird issues..

For example in one of my cucumber specs i create a bunch of fake records using factory girl.. usually this works fine but it seemed that it wasn't creating the records for some reason..

So I commented out all of my factory stuff and replaced it with this:

```
c = Contact.new(:first_name => "SOMEONE", :last_name => "COOL", :dob => 10.years.ago, :sex => "male")
if c.save
  puts "MYCOUNT: #{Contact.count}"
else
  puts "EXPLOSIONS!!!"
end
```

Running this as part of the cucumber suite outputs this:

```
MYCOUNT: 0
```

So the contact record is obviously being saved (and passing validations) yet it is still not showing up when i call count??

Why??

I am using:

Rails 3.1rc5

rspec-rails

cucumber-rails

and

factory_girl_rails

I should also probably note i'm indexing my models using sunspot (solr API) https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot

Comment: Can you run `c.reload` after save? Does it show up in `Contact.all`?

Comment: Sorry about the long wait.. Was on holiday :-)

Weirdest thing.. After running c.reload still nothing, it also doesnt show up in Contact.all.. i also checked c.new_record? and it's false..

This is just weird!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a transaction rollback firing within your test:

1) Transaction opened

2) Contact.save succeeds (now have legit Contact instance and db record)

3) Something goes wrong, raises ActiveRecord::Rollback

4) Transactions rolls back, leaving legit Contact instance but no db record, count = 0

I don't know what would cause this related to your Rails upgrade, but perhaps this will help you find what's failing.

EDIT:

If you tail your log/test.log file you should see a Rollback occur if this is the case.  You can look at the previous DB activity to get a clue as to what the last successful db operation was before it.

Not an exact science, but may help you decide if this is the case and get a rough idea of where it went sideways.

Comment: Thanks man! Is there any way of finding out when ActiveRecord::Rollback gets raised?

Comment: Edited to add some more detail about debugging this.  Good luck!  I hit a bug like this a week ago and it totally confused me at first.

Comment: Yep.. right on the money, tailed it and I get a rollback. Now comes the tricky bit, finding out where it's coming from! :P By the looks of it the last thing before the rollback is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`approved` = 1` (approved = 1 is the default scope).. the one before that is: `RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1`... other than the INSERT the only other thing before the rollback is `[paperclip] Saving attachments.` which I thought could be the culpret.. so i commented out my paperclip stuff and still no dice! argh!

Comment: Think i've figured out what was causing the bug :) it was an `after_initialize` workaround i'd forgotten about! Thanks for your help!